# perl regex wildcard not working on sub pattern grouping

Tags: regex, perl, wildcard

I have tried using sub pattern to match multiple occurrence of a word using wild card but it is not working. I tried to replace * with ? but still does not match anything. Only works when I used + and {1,} to specify the number of occurrence.

Can anyone explain?

```
$_ = "Larry has a  camel little little little camel has a little camel";
print "Matched:--$`<<$&>>$'--\n" if /(little )*/;
```

expected `Matched:--Larry has a  camel <<little little little >>camel has a little camel--`

output `Matched:--<<>>Larry has a  camel little little little camel has a little camel--`

Comment: Might I recommend `"use English;"` and change `$\`, $&, $'`, to respectively `$PREMATCH, $MATCH, $POSTMATCH` ? It will make your code a lot more readable and not make the reader hate Perl.

Comment: Check out Damian Conway's [Regexp::Debugger](https://metacpan.org/pod/Regexp::Debugger) for an interactive way to work through your regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to find the first place where there is *zero or more* repetitions of `"little "`. Zero repetitions of anything is an empty string, which can be found anywhere - and in fact, the first such place is at the start of the string. In fact, even `"big"` has four places where you can find zero or more repetitions of `"little "` (the first one being, of course, at the start of the string).

If you change `*` "zero or more" to `+` "one or more", it should work as you wish it to, as you found.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Using start `*` for string/char match will always be looking for zero repetition, unless the string/char is at the beginning of the string.

The best time to use * or ? will be using with meta-character such as \s \w ?

Comment: `*` is great if you have something else to anchor it, make it invalid for null-length. This problem only appears if your entire pattern can match a null-length sequence. For example, `camel (little )*` will match `"camel little little little "`, since the `camel` bit forces it to be nontrivial, and then, having found a spot it can actually find its match, greedy operator takes over and gobbles up everything it can.